# bootstrap carousel dissapears on host server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi my carousel dissapears when I move my wesite directiry from my local testing server(where everything works perfectly) to my webhosting platform.
Anyone know what could cause that?
thanks.  The html is under my other related question in my user profile?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED/Was due to a filename mismatch.